# Django REST Framework: Unique_together validation on Serializers

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Having issues with a `serializer.is_valid()` returning `True` if the serializer instance fails a `unique_together` constraint on the model side.

Is there a way for me to specify in the serializer to enforce a `unique_together` constraint?

Comment: Can you include the model in question?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unfortunately, Andreas's answer is not quite complete, as it will not work in the case of an update.

Instead, you would want something more like:

```
def validate(self, attrs):
    field1 = attrs.get('field1', self.object.field1)
    field2 = attrs.get('field2', self.object.field2)

    try:
        obj = Model.objects.get(field1=field1, field2=field2)
    except StateWithholdingForm.DoesNotExist:
        return attrs
    if self.object and obj.id == self.object.id:
        return attrs
    else:
        raise serializers.ValidationError('field1 with field2 already exists')
```

This will work for PUT, PATCH, and POST.

Comment: hmm interesting. i think you could also make it more efficient if you added `.exists()` instead of doing a straight-up get? not sure what the ramifications of not verifying the IDs would do

Comment: @fangsterr You're right, you could do something like: `objects.filter(field1=field1, field2=field2).exists()` In the case that you're updating an object though, a matching object will exist - the one you're updating, which is what that id comparison is about.

Comment: bit late lol but i think it updates the serializer before validating so the if `if self.object and obj.id == self.object.id:` is not needed as should never be called, at least thats what i found in my testing.

Answer (score 30):

The ModelSerializer class has this functionality build-in, at least in `djangorestframework>=3.0.0`, however if you are using a `serializer` which doesn't include *all* of the fields which are affected by your `unique_together`constrain, then you'll get an `IntegrityError` when saving an instance which violates it. For example, using the following model:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('foo_a', 'foo_b')

    a = models.TextField(blank=True)
    b = models.TextField(blank=True)
    foo_a = models.IntegerField()
    foo_b = models.IntegerField(default=2)
```

and the following serializer and ViewSet:

```
class FooSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Foo
        fields = ('a', 'b', 'foo_a')

class FooViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.Foo.objects.all()
    serializer_class = FooSerializer


routes = routers.DefaultRouter()
routes.register(r'foo', FooViewSet)
```

if you try to save two instances with the same `foo_a` and `foo_b` set, you'll get an `IntegrityError`. However, if we modify the serializer like this:

```
class FooSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Foo
        fields = ('a', 'b', 'foo_a', 'foo_b')
```

you'll then get a proper `HTTP 400 BAD REQUEST` status code, and the corresponding JSON descriptive message in the response body:

```
HTTP 400 BAD REQUEST
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept
Allow: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS

{
    "non_field_errors": [
        "The fields foo_a, foo_b must make a unique set."
    ]
}
```

I hope this to result helpful for you, even when this is a somewhat old-posted question ;-)

Comment: Any way to have this behavior without including the field in the serializer input / output? One of my field included in the unique_together is computed in the serializer validate method.

Comment: @MartinFaucheux you could probably use [`HiddenField`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#hiddenfield).

Answer (score 25):

I Needed this to override default message. Solved it by [this](https://gist.github.com/vaibhav-jain/91f49e8252ad4860b419868f704bbcf7).

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from rest_framework import serializers, validators


class SomeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  """
  Demostrating How to Override DRF UniqueTogetherValidator Message
  """

    class Meta:
        model = Some
        validators = [
            validators.UniqueTogetherValidator(
                queryset=model.objects.all(),
                fields=('field1', 'field2'),
                message=_("Some custom message.")
            )
        ]
```

Similarly, you can specify fields.

Comment: I need to check validation converting model fields lowercase value. is it possible using default validation or write custom .

Comment: thank you, i was facing same issue developing an ecommerce drf api and this solution worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can do it in the `.validate()` method of the serializer.

```py
def validate(self, attrs):
    try:
        Model.objects.get(field1=attrs['field1'], field2=attrs['field2'])
    except Model.DoesNotExist:
        pass
    else:
        raise serializers.ValidationError('field1 with field2 already exists')

    return attrs
```

The unique constraint that you set in your model is for creating database constraints, not for validating.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem and from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/26027788/6473175 I was able to get it to work but had to use `self.instance` instead of `self.object`.

```
def validate(self, data):
    field1 = data.get('field1',None)
    field2 = data.get('field2',None)

    try:
        obj = self.Meta.model.objects.get(field1=field1, field2=field2)
    except self.Meta.model.DoesNotExist:
        return data
    if self.instance and obj.id == self.instance.id:
        return data
    else:
        raise serializers.ValidationError('custom error message')
```

Answer (score -1):

Well this is kinda stupid and it's very unlikely that anyone but me would make this mistake, but I had put the same model in two serializers class, as a consequence I had this problem

Hope my mistake help someone!